# Why is named list column in a tibble converted to list when using filter

Tags: r, dplyr

there is a tibble which contains named list val column.

```
tibble = tibble::tibble(val = list(list(1,2), list(3,2), list("a","b")),
                        name = c("a", "b", "c"))
names(tibble$val) = tibble$name
tibble
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  val          name 
  <named list> <chr>
1 <list [2]>   a    
2 <list [2]>   b    
3 <list [2]>   c
```

However, names in val column vanish when using filter.
Could you tell me how to avoid this?

```
  tibble %>% 
    dplyr::filter(name %in% c("a", "b"))  
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  val        name 
  <list>     <chr>
1 <list [2]> a    
2 <list [2]> b
```

Comment: With R-4.0.1, `tibble-3.0.1`, and `dplyr-1.0.0`, I see `<named list>` in both outputs.

Comment: On further research (R-3.5.3 and `dplyr-0.8.3`), its `filter_impl` function appears to be stripping the names.

Comment: Thanks.It is true that the version of  dplyr in RStudio is 0.8.3.I will try update